# Weekday selector in Rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, simple-form

I have an `Schedule` model where user selects hours and specific days of week (e.g `3hrs` `monday, tuesday, saturday`). My migration looks like

```
 class CreateSchedules < ActiveRecord::Migration
 def change
 create_table :schedules do |t|
  t.integer :hourss
  t.integer :user_id
  t.boolean :monday
  t.boolean :tuesday
  t.boolean :wednesday
  t.boolean :thursday
  t.boolean :friday
  t.boolean :saturday
  t.boolean :sunday

  t.timestamps
end
end
end
```

How do I write form in views to show checkbox for weekdays and one selects some, boolean value should be set to true. I am using `Simple Form` and Rails 3.2.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With simple form its really easy. Just do

= f.input :monday

= f.input :tuesday

etc. Simple form auto converts boolean db items to checkboxes